# get change trend of amount purchase based on previous records of a specific record in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trend

I have a table that has these Information:
date of customer purchase, purchase amount, date difference interval between a purchase and previous purchase, purchae amount difference betweeen a purchase and previous purchase.

| ID | CustNumber | Date | Amount | DateDiffFromLastPurchase | AmountDiffFromLastPurchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2022-01-02 | 1000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 101 | 2022-02-04 | 1000 | 32 | 0 |
| 3 | 101 | 2022-03-01 | 1000 | 27 | 0 |
| 4 | 101 | 2022-03-19 | 1000 | 18 | 0 |
| 5 | 101 | 2022-04-02 | 2000 | 13 | 1000 |
| 6 | 101 | 2022-04-10 | 4000 | 8 | 2000 |
| 7 | 101 | 2022-04-20 | 2000 | 10 | -2000 |
| 8 | 101 | 2022-05-20 | 1000 | 30 | -1000 |
| 9 | 101 | 2022-06-20 | 2000 | 30 | 1000 |
| 10 | 101 | 2022-07-10 | 3000 | 20 | 1000 |
| 11 | 101 | 2022-07-30 | 4000 | 20 | 1000 |
| 12 | 101 | 2022-08-30 | 4000 | 30 | 0 |

Now I want to add a field to this table , that shows the trend of changes in the amount of customer purchases in the previous days before today.
The desired table should be as follows:

| ID | CustomerNumber | PurchaseDate | PurchaseAmount | DateDiffFromPreviousPurchase | AmountDiffFromPreviousPurchase | ChangeTrend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2022-01-02 | 1000 | 0 | 0 | Without change |
| 2 | 101 | 2022-02-04 | 1000 | 32 | 0 | Without change |
| 3 | 101 | 2022-03-01 | 1000 | 27 | 0 | Without change |
| 4 | 101 | 2022-03-19 | 1000 | 18 | 0 | Without change |
| 5 | 101 | 2022-04-02 | 2000 | 13 | 1000 | Without change |
| 6 | 101 | 2022-04-10 | 4000 | 8 | 2000 | ascending |
| 7 | 101 | 2022-04-20 | 2000 | 10 | -2000 | ascending |
| 8 | 101 | 2022-05-20 | 1000 | 30 | -1000 | ascending then descending, like Sinusoidal trend |
| 9 | 101 | 2022-06-20 | 2000 | 30 | 1000 | ascending then descending, like Sinusoidal trend |
| 10 | 101 | 2022-07-10 | 3000 | 20 | 1000 | Sinusoidal trend |
| 11 | 101 | 2022-07-30 | 4000 | 20 | 1000 | Sinusoidal trend |
| 12 | 101 | 2022-08-30 | 4000 | 30 | 0 | Sinusoidal trend |

assume that you have x axis and y axis,x will be amount Of all prevoius purchase of a customer and y will be date of all previous purchase. Each purchase will have a point on our 2D chart. By connecting these points we will reach a curve. How is this curve? Ascending Descending? sinus? Show? A line without slope?

I do not Know how to implement this in SQLserver, can anybody help me how to do this or give me  a better suggestion to show how the data changes?

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: I really don't follow the logic here. You're just put sample data and expected results here and expect us to *guess* what the logic is to get the expected results. *Explain* the problem. Define when the different values in your column(s) should appear. Explain the difficulty *you* are having solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @ThomA The problem is finding purchase trend of a customer  based on his past purchases. assume that you have x axis and y axis,x will be amount Of all prevoius purchase of a customer and y will be date of all previous purchase. Each purchase will have a point on our 2D chart. By connecting these points we will reach a curve. How is this curve? Ascending Descending? sinus? Show? A line without slope?

Answer (score 0):

This query does not answer the question in full because your question doesn't completely explain the desired results and what you use to calculate the trends.

You can use windowed functions to solve the problem:

```
select *,
 CASE 
            WHEN 
                 LAG(PurchaseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNumber ORDER BY PurchaseDate ) < PurchaseAmount THEN 'ascending' 
            WHEN
                 LAG(PurchaseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNumber ORDER BY PurchaseDate) = PurchaseAmount THEN 'Without change'
            WHEN
                 LAG(PurchaseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNumber ORDER BY PurchaseDate) > PurchaseAmount THEN 'descending'
            ELSE 'Without change'
        END As Trend  
 

from datas
order by id
```

You can insert the basic data with the following statements:

```
drop table  if exists datas
create table datas
(
ID int, CustomerNumber  int,    PurchaseDate date,
PurchaseAmount  int,    DateDiffFromLastPurchase int,
AmountDiffFromLastPurchase  int
)

insert into datas
(ID ,CustomerNumber,PurchaseDate ,
PurchaseAmount,DateDiffFromLastPurchase , AmountDiffFromLastPurchase  )
        select  '1',    '101',  '2022-01-02',   1000,   0 ,0
union select '2',   '101',  '2022-02-04',   1000,   32,0
union select '3',   '101',  '2022-03-01',   1000,   27,0
union select '4',   '101',  '2022-03-19',   1000,   18,0
union select '5',   '101',  '2022-04-02',   2000,   13,1000
union select '6',   '101',  '2022-04-10',   4000,   8,2000
union select '7',   '101',  '2022-04-20',   2000,   10,-2000
union select '8',   '101',  '2022-05-20',   1000,   30,-1000
union select '9',   '101',  '2022-06-20',   2000,   30,1000
union select '10',  '101',  '2022-07-10',   3000,   20,1000
union select '11',  '101',  '2022-07-30',   4000,   20,1000
union select '12',  '101',  '2022-08-30',   4000,   30,0
```